# Take max with condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a transaction date `txn_date` and 6 more date columns (`date_1`, `date_2`, etc) that can take values after or before the `txn_date` for a given observation.

I need to take the max of the `date_` s for a given observation but only taking the max amongst the dates that are less than the `txn_date`.

Date frame looks like this (all columns as.Date in the actual date frame but just numeric here for ease)

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "txn_date date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3 date_4 date_5 
50 30 40 50 60 70 75
60 30 40 50 60 70 75", header = TRUE)
```

And ideally it would look like this:

```
dat1 <- read.table(text = "txn_date date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3 date_4 date_5 max
50 30 40 50 60 70 75 40
60 30 40 50 60 70 75 50", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another base R option using `max.col`

```
dat1$Max <- dat1[-1][
  cbind(
    1:nrow(dat1),
    max.col(dat1[-1] < dat1[, 1], ties.method = "last")
  )
]
```

gives

```
> dat1
  txn_date date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3 date_4 date_5 Max
1       50     30     40     50     60     70     75  40
2       60     30     40     50     60     70     75  50
```

---

```
dat1$max <- apply(dat1, 1, function(x) max(x[-1][x[-1] < x[1]], na.rm = TRUE))
dat1$max
[1] 40 50
```

If there are rows that doesn't meet the condition, use an if/else

```
apply(dat1, 1, function(x) if(any(x[-1] < x[1])) max(x[-1][x[-1] < x[1]], na.rm = TRUE) else NA_real_)
[1] 40 50
```

---

We could use apply in base R

```
dat1$max <- apply(dat1, 1, function(x) max(x[-1][x[-1] < x[1]], na.rm = TRUE))
dat1$max
[1] 40 50
```

If there are rows that doesn't meet the condition, use an if/else

```
apply(dat1, 1, function(x) if(any(x[-1] < x[1])) max(x[-1][x[-1] < x[1]], na.rm = TRUE) else NA_real_)
[1] 40 50
```

Or use a much faster version of apply with dapply (from collapse)

```
library(collapse)
dapply(dat1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x)
       max(x[-1][x[-1] < x[1]], na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 40 50
```

Or make it faster with a vectorized option

```
do.call(pmax, c(replace(dat1[-1], dat1[-1] >= dat1[[1]], NA), na.rm = TRUE))
[1] 40 50
```

Or using tidyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
dat1 %>%
    mutate(max = pmap_dbl(., ~ {
                 tmp <- c(...)
                 max(tmp[-1][tmp[-1] < tmp[1]], na.rm = TRUE)}))
```

-outupt

```
   txn_date date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3 date_4 date_5 max
1       50     30     40     50     60     70     75  40
2       60     30     40     50     60     70     75  50
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` and `purrr` with `rowwise()`and `max`, `keep`ing only columns with values < txn_date to feed to `max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat1 %>% rowwise() %>%
        mutate(max=max(keep(c_across(date_0:date_5), ~ .x < txn_date), na.rm=TRUE))

# A tibble: 2 x 8
# Rowwise: 
  txn_date date_0 date_1 date_2 date_3 date_4 date_5   max
     <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int> <int>
1       50     30     40     50     60     70     75    40
2       60     30     40     50     60     70     75    50
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: roblem with `mutate()` input `max`.
✖ Predicate functions must return a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not a missing value
ℹ Input `max` is `max(...)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.

Comment: THat means you probably have row in which all values in date_0:date_5 are > txn_date.

Comment: This solution worked fine in the example dataset, can you check if that is the case?

Comment: Yeah it does work in the example data set, sorry about that. I'm wondering why it won't just take the max even if they are all < txn_date. Is there not a way to do that with this?

Comment: Do you want NAs in these cases?

Comment: I meant all > thant txn_date, not < as in my previous comment

Comment: I would like to just ignore NAs, so if we replaced date_4 in the first row of the example data with NA the max should still be 40

Comment: If all > than txn_date then max = NA

Comment: My solution returns the same even with NAs as in the NA in date_4 example. The problem is when the predicate function in keep returns NA, which probably happens when all values are > txn_date

Comment: I found a solution with `pmap` but it is identical to the answer by @akrun